# Implementing search functionality for a deeply nested object in Javscript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion, search

I want to have a *search* functionality in my app, which should search within an *object* and give the results back in the same format as the input object. For *example*, my data object is-

```
const obj = {
  Cricket: {
    description: "",
    stadiums: {
      Australia: {
        Melbourne: {
          match: "IND VS ENG",
        },
        Sydney: {
          match: "BAN VS PAK",
        },
      },
      India: {
        Wankhede: {
          match: "NZ VS AUS",
        },
        Eden_Gardens: {
          match: "SA VS WI",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  Football: {
    description: "",
    stadiums: {
      UK: {
        Trafford: {
          match: "MU VS AR",
        },
        Emirates: {
          name: "LIV VS MC",
        },
      },
      Spain: {
        Wanda: {
          match: "RM VS BOC",
        },
        Santiago: {
          match: "BAR VS VIL",
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

***SCENARIOS :***

***Input***

User searches for '*Cric*'

***Output***

```
{
  Cricket: {
    description: '',
    stadiums: { Australia: [Object], India: [Object] }
  }
}
```

***Input***

User searches for '*tiago*'

***Output***

```
{
  Football: {
    description: '',
    stadiums: { Spain: [Object] }
  }
}
```

***Approach***

I coded the solution for the above problem like below, the issue which I am facing is, I am not able to return all the keys from the parent object, for example in *Scenario 2* above, my code doesn't return me the *description* key.

```
 const search = (obj, text) => {
    const searchRegex = RegExp(text, 'i');
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (searchRegex.test(curr) && typeof obj[curr] === 'object') {
        acc[curr] = obj[curr];
      } else {
        if (typeof obj[curr] === 'object') {
          const result = search(obj[curr], text);
          if (Object.keys(result).length > 0) {
            acc[curr] = result;
          }
        }
      }
      return acc;
    }, {});
  };
```

Please help on how can I achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: @LeeTaylor I want fuzzy search, so tiago as well as santiago should return the same result

Comment: How do you decide that you want `"Football.description"`, but not `"Football.stadiums.UK"`, when you match `"Football.stadiums.Spain.Santiago"`?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yeah, I guess I haven't framed a better example for my use case. Let me revisit the example and update it, in order to provide a clear understanding. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I keep a handy set of object manipulation tools that often make such things easier.

Using these tools, the only new code I had to write is:

```js
const deepKeySearch = (term, t = term.toLowerCase()) => 
  deepFilter (([path]) => String (path .at (-1) .toLowerCase ()) .includes (t))
```

Obviously, this could be simplified a bit if you only wanted case-sensitive comparisons.

This technique starts by converting the object to a list of what I call *pathEntries*, which are two-element arrays: the first is an array of node names and the second the value at that path in the object.  For instance,

```js
  [["Football"], {"description": "", "stadiums": {...}}}]
```

is the `"Football"` node of our main object, and the value at that node.

and

```js
  [["Football", "stadiums", "UK", "Trafford", "match"], "MU VS AR"]
```

is the `"match"` node of the `"Trafford"` node of the `"UK"` node of the `"stadiums"` node of the `"Football"` node of our main object, and the string "MU VS AR" at that path.

The whole object turns into:

```js
[
  [["Cricket"], {"description": "", "stadiums": {"Australia": {"Melbourne": {"match": "IND VS ENG"}, "Sydney": {"match": "BAN VS PAK"}}, "India": {"Eden_Gardens": {"match": "SA VS WI"}, "Wankhede": {"match": "NZ VS AUS"}}}}],
  [["Cricket", "description"], ""], 
  [["Cricket", "stadiums"], {"Australia": {"Melbourne": {"match": "IND VS ENG"}, "Sydney": {"match": "BAN VS PAK"}}, "India": {"Eden_Gardens": {"match": "SA VS WI"}, "Wankhede": {"match": "NZ VS AUS"}}}], 
  [["Cricket", "stadiums", "Australia"], {"Melbourne": {"match": "IND VS ENG"}, "Sydney": {"match": "BAN VS PAK"}}], 
  [["Cricket", "stadiums", "Australia", "Melbourne"], {"match": "IND VS ENG"}], 
  [["Cricket", "stadiums", "Australia", "Melbourne", "match"], "IND VS ENG"], 
  [["Cricket", "stadiums", "Australia", "Sydney"], {"match": "BAN VS PAK"}], 
  [["Cricket", "stadiums", "Australia", "Sydney", "match"], "BAN VS PAK"], 
  [["Cricket", "stadiums", "India"], {"Eden_Gardens": {"match": "SA VS WI"}, "Wankhede": {"match": "NZ VS AUS"}}], 
  [["Cricket", "stadiums", "India", "Wankhede"], {"match": "NZ VS AUS"}], 
  [["Cricket", "stadiums", "India", "Wankhede", "match"], "NZ VS AUS"],
  [["Cricket", "stadiums", "India", "Eden_Gardens"], {"match": "SA VS WI"}], 
  [["Cricket", "stadiums", "India", "Eden_Gardens", "match"], "SA VS WI"], 
  [["Football"], {"description": "", "stadiums": {"Spain": {"Santiago": {"match": "BAR VS VIL"}, "Wanda": {"match": "RM VS BOC"}}, "UK": {"Emirates": {"name": "LIV VS MC"}, "Trafford": {"match": "MU VS AR"}}}}],
  [["Football", "description"], ""],
  [["Football", "stadiums"], {"Spain": {"Santiago": {"match": "BAR VS VIL"}, "Wanda": {"match": "RM VS BOC"}}, "UK": {"Emirates": {"name": "LIV VS MC"}, "Trafford": {"match": "MU VS AR"}}}],
  [["Football", "stadiums", "UK"], {"Emirates": {"name": "LIV VS MC"}, "Trafford": {"match": "MU VS AR"}}],
  [["Football", "stadiums", "UK", "Trafford"], {"match": "MU VS AR"}],
  [["Football", "stadiums", "UK", "Trafford", "match"], "MU VS AR"],
  [["Football", "stadiums", "UK", "Emirates"], {"name": "LIV VS MC"}],
  [["Football", "stadiums", "UK", "Emirates", "name"], "LIV VS MC"],
  [["Football", "stadiums", "Spain"], {"Santiago": {"match": "BAR VS VIL"}, "Wanda": {"match": "RM VS BOC"}}],
  [["Football", "stadiums", "Spain", "Wanda"], {"match": "RM VS BOC"}], 
  [["Football", "stadiums", "Spain", "Wanda", "match"], "RM VS BOC"],
  [["Football", "stadiums", "Spain", "Santiago"], {"match": "BAR VS VIL"}], 
  [["Football", "stadiums", "Spain", "Santiago", "match"], "BAR VS VIL"]
]
```

A generic function, `deepFilter` lets us create a stripped-down version of the object keeping only those nodes that match the predicate supplied (plus of course their entire ancestry.)  This is built on `pathEntries` above and `hydrate`.  `hydrate` is simply a fold of the function `setPath` over the matching values.  `setPath` recursively adds nodes to an object using the path and the value from the pathEntry.

Finally, our `deepKeySearch` passes a simple predicate to `deepFilter`, which checks if the last node name on the path contains the query string.

This will then let us test, say, for the string `"nd"`, which will match `"India"` and `"Wanda"`, yielding this:

```js
{
    Cricket: {
        stadiums: {
            India: {
                Eden_Gardens: {
                    match: "SA VS WI"
                },
                Wankhede: {
                    match: "NZ VS AUS"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    Football: {
        stadiums: {
            Spain: {
                Wanda: {
                    match: "RM VS BOC"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Together, it looks like this:

```js
const pathEntries = (o, path = []) => [
  ... (path .length > 0 ? [[path, o]] : []),
  ... (Object (o) === o ? Object .entries (o) .flatMap (
        ([k, v], _, __, key = Array .isArray (o) ? Number (k) : k) => pathEntries (v, [...path, key])) : []
      )
]

const setPath = ([p, ...ps]) => (v) => (o) =>
  p == undefined ? v : Object .assign (
    Array .isArray (o) || Number.isInteger (p) ? [] : {},
    {...o, [p]: setPath (ps) (v) ((o || {}) [p])}
  )

const hydrate = (xs) =>
  xs .reduce ((a, [p, v]) => setPath (p) (v) (a), {})
 
const deepFilter = (pred) => (o) =>
  hydrate (pathEntries (o) .filter (pred))

const deepKeySearch = (term, t = term.toLowerCase()) => 
  deepFilter (([path]) => String (path .at (-1) .toLowerCase ()) .includes (t))

const obj = {Cricket: {description: "", stadiums: {Australia: {Melbourne: {match: "IND VS ENG"}, Sydney: {match: "BAN VS PAK"}}, India: {Wankhede: {match: "NZ VS AUS"}, Eden_Gardens: {match: "SA VS WI"}}}}, Football: {description: "", stadiums: {UK: {Trafford: {match: "MU VS AR"}, Emirates: {name: "LIV VS MC"}}, Spain: {Wanda: {match: "RM VS BOC"}, Santiago: {match: "BAR VS VIL"}}}}}

console .log ('"Cric":\n', deepKeySearch ('Cric') (obj))
console .log ('"tiago":\n', deepKeySearch ('tiago') (obj))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

You can see [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1243641%20hydrate) that use similar functions.  (This one uses a variant of my usual `pathEntries` that captures all nodes, instead of only leaf nodes.) The point is that a set of useful reusable functions can make a lot of problems simpler to solve.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I do want to retain the unmatched keys from the parent element like what I mentioned in the question. For example 2, I want the description key to be retained in the Football object.

Comment: While I must admit that I did miss that, I think you'll need a better specification.  How do you decide that you want `"Football.description"`, but not `"Football.stadiums.UK"`, when you match `"Football.stadiums.Spain.Santiago"`?